# How can I use turn.js javascript library with vue js, laravel project

Tags: jquery, laravel, vue.js, flip, turnjs

I am relatively new to Vuejs. I am working on a vuejs (front end) and Laravel (Backend) project. ***I wanted to integrate a Jquery library named turn.js in my project***. But I am facing errors. As, I have been able to run jquery in vue Mounted() hook, ***but the yepnope js is not working***. ***How can I use the turn.js opensource library dynamically in my vuejs laravel project***. my vue js code is here

```
<script>
export default {
    data:() => {
        return {

        }
    },

    mounted() {
        function loadApp() {

            $('#canvas').fadeIn(1000);

            var flipbook = $('.magazine');

            // Check if the CSS was already loaded
            
            if (flipbook.width()==0 || flipbook.height()==0) {
                setTimeout(loadApp, 10);
                return;
            }
            
            // Create the flipbook

            flipbook.turn({
                    
                    // Magazine width

                    width: 922,

                    // Magazine height

                    height: 600,

                    // Duration in millisecond

                    duration: 1000,

                    // Hardware acceleration

                    acceleration: !isChrome(),

                    // Enables gradients

                    gradients: true,
                    
                    // Auto center this flipbook

                    autoCenter: true,

                    // Elevation from the edge of the flipbook when turning a page

                    elevation: 50,

                    // The number of pages

                    pages: 12,

                    // Events

                    when: {
                        turning: function(event, page, view) {
                            
                            var book = $(this),
                            currentPage = book.turn('page'),
                            pages = book.turn('pages');
                    
                            // Update the current URI

                            Hash.go('page/' + page).update();

                            // Show and hide navigation buttons

                            disableControls(page);
                            

                            $('.thumbnails .page-'+currentPage).
                                parent().
                                removeClass('current');

                            $('.thumbnails .page-'+page).
                                parent().
                                addClass('current');



                        },

                        turned: function(event, page, view) {

                            disableControls(page);

                            $(this).turn('center');

                            if (page==1) { 
                                $(this).turn('peel', 'br');
                            }

                        },

                        missing: function (event, pages) {

                            // Add pages that aren't in the magazine

                            for (var i = 0; i < pages.length; i++)
                                addPage(pages[i], $(this));

                        }
                    }

            });

            // Zoom.js

            $('.magazine-viewport').zoom({
                flipbook: $('.magazine'),

                max: function() { 
                    
                    return largeMagazineWidth()/$('.magazine').width();

                }, 

                when: {

                    swipeLeft: function() {

                        $(this).zoom('flipbook').turn('next');

                    },

                    swipeRight: function() {
                        
                        $(this).zoom('flipbook').turn('previous');

                    },

                    // zoom page zoomin and page zoomout workflow
                    
                    // resize: function(event, scale, page, pageElement) {

                    //  if (scale==1)
                    //      loadSmallPage(page, pageElement);
                    //  else
                    //      loadLargePage(page, pageElement);

                    // },
                    // zoom page zoomin and page zoomout workflow

                    zoomIn: function () {

                        $('.thumbnails').hide();
                        $('.made').hide();
                        $('.magazine').removeClass('animated').addClass('zoom-in');
                        $('.zoom-icon').removeClass('zoom-icon-in').addClass('zoom-icon-out');
                        
                        if (!window.escTip && !$.isTouch) {
                            escTip = true;

                            $('<div />', {'class': 'exit-message'}).
                                html('<div>Press ESC to exit</div>').
                                    appendTo($('body')).
                                    delay(2000).
                                    animate({opacity:0}, 500, function() {
                                        $(this).remove();
                                    });
                        }
                    },

                    zoomOut: function() {

                        $('.exit-message').hide();
                        $('.thumbnails').fadeIn();
                        $('.made').fadeIn();
                        $('.zoom-icon').removeClass('zoom-icon-out').addClass('zoom-icon-in');

                        setTimeout(function(){
                            $('.magazine').addClass('animated').removeClass('zoom-in');
                            resizeViewport();
                        }, 0);

                    }
                }
            });

            // Zoom event

            if ($.isTouch)
                $('.magazine-viewport').bind('zoom.doubleTap', zoomTo);
            else
                $('.magazine-viewport').bind('zoom.tap', zoomTo);


            // Using arrow keys to turn the page

            $(document).keydown(function(e){

                var previous = 37, next = 39, esc = 27;

                switch (e.keyCode) {
                    case previous:

                        // left arrow
                        $('.magazine').turn('previous');
                        e.preventDefault();

                    break;
                    case next:

                        //right arrow
                        $('.magazine').turn('next');
                        e.preventDefault();

                    break;
                    case esc:
                        
                        $('.magazine-viewport').zoom('zoomOut');    
                        e.preventDefault();

                    break;
                }
            });

            // URIs - Format #/page/1 
            //regular expression ^page = page should be at the beginning of string
            // ([0-9]*) means the 0-9 should be 0 or more times in the matching string
            // $ is used to search characters at the end of the string


            Hash.on('^page\/([0-9]*)$', {
                yep: function(path, parts) {
                    var page = parts[1];

                    if (page!==undefined) {
                        if ($('.magazine').turn('is'))
                            $('.magazine').turn('page', page);
                    }

                },
                nop: function(path) {

                    if ($('.magazine').turn('is'))
                        $('.magazine').turn('page', 1);
                }
            });


            $(window).resize(function() {
                resizeViewport();
            }).bind('orientationchange', function() {
                resizeViewport();
            });

            // Events for thumbnails

            $('.thumbnails').click(function(event) {
                
                var page;

                if (event.target && (page=/page-([0-9]+)/.exec($(event.target).attr('class'))) ) {
                
                    $('.magazine').turn('page', page[1]);
                }
            });

            $('.thumbnails li').
                bind($.mouseEvents.over, function() {
                    
                    $(this).addClass('thumb-hover');

                }).bind($.mouseEvents.out, function() {
                    
                    $(this).removeClass('thumb-hover');

                });

            if ($.isTouch) {
            
                $('.thumbnails').
                    addClass('thumbanils-touch').
                    bind($.mouseEvents.move, function(event) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                    });

            } else {

                $('.thumbnails ul').mouseover(function() {

                    $('.thumbnails').addClass('thumbnails-hover');

                }).mousedown(function() {

                    return false;

                }).mouseout(function() {

                    $('.thumbnails').removeClass('thumbnails-hover');

                });

            }


            // Regions

            if ($.isTouch) {
                $('.magazine').bind('touchstart', regionClick);
            } else {
                $('.magazine').click(regionClick);
            }

            // Events for the next button

            $('.next-button').bind($.mouseEvents.over, function() {
                
                $(this).addClass('next-button-hover');

            }).bind($.mouseEvents.out, function() {
                
                $(this).removeClass('next-button-hover');

            }).bind($.mouseEvents.down, function() {
                
                $(this).addClass('next-button-down');

            }).bind($.mouseEvents.up, function() {
                
                $(this).removeClass('next-button-down');

            }).click(function() {
                
                $('.magazine').turn('next');

            });

            // Events for the next button
            
            $('.previous-button').bind($.mouseEvents.over, function() {
                
                $(this).addClass('previous-button-hover');

            }).bind($.mouseEvents.out, function() {
                
                $(this).removeClass('previous-button-hover');

            }).bind($.mouseEvents.down, function() {
                
                $(this).addClass('previous-button-down');

            }).bind($.mouseEvents.up, function() {
                
                $(this).removeClass('previous-button-down');

            }).click(function() {
                
                $('.magazine').turn('previous');

            });


            resizeViewport();

            $('.magazine').addClass('animated');

        };

        // Zoom icon

        $('.zoom-icon').bind('mouseover', function() { 
            
            if ($(this).hasClass('zoom-icon-in'))
                $(this).addClass('zoom-icon-in-hover');

            if ($(this).hasClass('zoom-icon-out'))
                $(this).addClass('zoom-icon-out-hover');
        
        }).bind('mouseout', function() { 
            
            if ($(this).hasClass('zoom-icon-in'))
                $(this).removeClass('zoom-icon-in-hover');
            
            if ($(this).hasClass('zoom-icon-out'))
                $(this).removeClass('zoom-icon-out-hover');

        }).bind('click', function() {

            if ($(this).hasClass('zoom-icon-in'))
                $('.magazine-viewport').zoom('zoomIn');
            else if ($(this).hasClass('zoom-icon-out')) 
                $('.magazine-viewport').zoom('zoomOut');

        });

        $('#canvas').hide();


        // Load the HTML4 version if there's not CSS transform

        yepnope({
            test : Modernizr.csstransforms,
            yep: ['../../../../public/js/lib/turn.js'],
            nope: ['../../../../public/js/lib/turn.html4.min.js'],
            both: ['../../../../public/js/lib/zoom.min.js', '../../../../public/js/megazine/js/magazine.js', '../../../../public/js/megazine/css/magazine.css'],
            complete: loadApp
        });


        function changePage(){
            pageNo = $('#changePage-number').val();
            // alert(pageNo);

            var flipbook = $('.magazine');

            flipbook.turn("page", pageNo);
        }
    },
}
```

The error I am facing is

```
Error in mounted hook: "ReferenceError: yepnope is not defined"
```

***I want to use turnjs in my project***. How can I achieve my goal. I have seen ***flipbook-vue*** which I can use but ***there is no documentation*** of that and I also don't know if that is ***opensource*** or not.
Thank You all in advance for your time. I really need your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

There is a component called vue-turnjs ([0](https://reidond.gitbook.io/vue-turnjs/)) that might be helpful.